# BillingState Issue

Tags: apex, trigger, account, before-trigger, update

i am trying to get BillingState value from apex trigger before insert, before update. I have troubles when change the value it got the last one and not the actual value

[image]

I do a debug and get the last BillingState value

[image]

It is wrong because i need 'Cauca', this happen when i update the record account.

Trigger here.

[image]

Class

```java
public class ValidacionCiudadAcc {
  public static void calculateCodeCity(List<Account> cuentas){
     for(Account ValidacionCiudad : cuentas){
        System.debug('BillingCity = ' + ValidacionCiudad.BillingCity);
        System.debug('BillingState = ' + ValidacionCiudad.BillingState);
     }
  }
}
```

trigger

```java
trigger ValidacionCiudadAcc on Account (before insert, before update) {
    for(Account ValidacionCiudad : trigger.New){    
        ValidacionCiudadAcc.calculateCodeCity(Trigger.New);  
    } 
}
```

My intention is depend of BillingState and BillingCity selected, put automatically the ZipCode, i have the list of cities and states, but they are to long so don show here cause each one have more than 1000 positions, the problem is when i try to get the value show me the last value and no the new (it is what i need for comparate with list of states).

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Providing code as text instead of an image is highly preferred (images become unreadable when lines become long, and text allows copy/pasting if someone tries to reproduce your issue). Calling your `calculateCodeCity()` method inside of a loop seems a bit odd (seeing as how you're passing `Trigger.new`) and may be part of the issue, but I think we'll need to see your `calculateCodeCity()` method to be able to get to the root of the problem. You can [edit] your question to add additional details like that.

Comment: *Bienvenidos a* Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! To expound on what @DerekF said, `Trigger.new` is always a `List`. (It could theoretically contain only one record, but it is still a `List`.) If it were not a `List`, you could not iterate through it like you are with your `for` loop. So if your trigger happens to get triggered by a `List` which contains more than one Account record, you will call your `calculateCodeCity()` method multiple times using the same list of records. Not only is it a waste of resources, but as Derek mentioned it could cause other issues & could be difficult to debug.

Comment: I have edited my question, thank you !!

Comment: are you using state and country picklists?  if so, you need to reference `BillingStateCode`